# Como ignorar uma coluna que não exista no banco de dados para as funcionalidades Select e Insert com JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

### Spring com JPA

Imaginem o cenário:

criado a query select com campos específicos (sem uso do * asterísco) e "uma coluna que não exista
no BD", ex.: coluna Situação

criado a entidade com os mesmos campos específicos da query

criado um método para buscar.

criado um método para salvar.

**Erro: Ao salvar, o JPA faz uma busca na entidade antes e verifica as colunas,
quando depara com a coluna que não existe no banco, ele estoura o erro de coluna não encontrada.**

O que tentei:

1. Criei uma segunda entidade com as colunas reais do BD para realizar o insert.
2. Usar ***@Transient*** e/ou ***insertable = false***.

A opção 1 funcionou, porém não queria criar duas entidades para cada uma dessa funcionalidades.

A opção 2 não funcionou para exibir a coluna Situação na interface, mas funcionou para inserção no BD.

Resumo:

Alguém teria alguma ideia a mais de como fazer com que a entidade seja uma só para todas funcionalidades, até mesmo quando uma coluna do banco não existir e somente existir em memória para exibição na interface?

Comment: opa @RicardoPontual eu entendi de outra forma, pelo que eu entendi, essa coluna que o AP se refere, parece ser um `campo calculado` (um valor derivado de alguma outra coluna) e só deveria existir em tempo de execução.. Mas não deseja que seja persistido.

Comment: @Danizavtz isso aí. Quero que sirva apenas para View mas não para ser persistido.

Answer (score -1):

Como é calculado o valor do campo/coluna `SITUAÇÃO` quando a entidade é criada em memória?

Você diz que a opção `@Transient` funciona para a comunicação com o banco de dados, mas não para exibição do dado. Bom, depende de como esse valor é obtido - já que, como sabemos, não foi salvo no banco de dados.

Vou tentar explicar através de um exemplo bem simples.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_PESSOA")
public class Pessoa {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    @Transient
    private String nomeCompleto;

    public Entidade(String nome, String sobrenome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        this.nomeCompleto = nome + " " + sobrenome;
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

Nesse exemplo, a entidade `Pessoa` possui 4 campos: *id, nome, sobrenome, nomeCompleto*. Entretanto, a tabela `TB_PESSOA` possui apenas 3 colunas: *id, nome, sobrenome*.

Campos com a anotação `@Transient`, por não existirem na tabela, não serão preenchidos pelo provedor de persistência. Preencher seu valor, portanto, é uma tarefa da aplicação. E faz sentido que seja assim.

Answer (score -3):

na hora de você fazer a query esse campo que nao existe ou campo calculado pode ser atribuído um null ou zero, exemplo:

```
select 
  a.nrounico,
  a.descricao,
  "" as grupo,
  0 as total
from produto a
```

só adaptar para JPQL que deverá dar certo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).